# doing logic operations in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to do logic operations OR,NOT, AND with vba but I'm having trouble with my code its not incrementing the values i know its probably(hopefully) a easy fix error any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sub logicop ()

Dim myRange As range
Dim rowi As range
Dim cell As range

Set myRange = Range("A8:F20") 'go into each row of column
For Each rowi In myeRange.Rows 
    andfunc = 1 'AND operaton
    notfunc = 0 'NOT function
    result1 = 0
    result2 = 0
    result3 = 0
For Each cell In rowi.Cells  'go into each cell of the rows in rowi

        If cell.Value = notfunc Then
         resuslt1 = result1 + 1
         End If

         If cell.Value = andfunc Then
         resuslt2 = result2 + 1
         End If

         If cell.Value <> andfunc And cell.Value <> notfun Then
          result3 = result3 + 1
          End If

  Next cell
Next

   result1 = Cells(3,3 )
   result2 = Cells(3, 4)
   result3 = Cells(3,5)

End Sub
```

Comment: `notfun` should be `notfunc`.  (Actually that probably won't help, because the undefined variable `notfun` will probably have a value of 0 which is the same value that `notfunc` has.)

Comment: More probably, the error may be caused by `myeRange.Rows` being used instead of `myRange.Rows`.  I **strongly** recommend you include an Option Explicit at the start of your module.

Comment: Why bother with the loops when you are going to set `result1` and `result2` and `result3` to three specific cells ??

Comment: And before it sets result1, result2 and result3 to three specific cells (as @Gary'sStudent pointed out), it calculates the number of 1s, 0s and others in row 20 (and ignores all other rows).

Comment: You have also misspelled `resuslt1` and `resuslt2`. And a +1 for the **OPTION EXPLICIT** comment above.

Comment: I think they're trying to put the results INTO the cells.  If so, the correct syntax is `Cells(3,3) = result1` for instance.

Comment: You might also consider using Excel formulae for this, i.e. (assuming we understand what your code is intended to do) C3 is `=COUNTIF(A8:F20,1)`, D3 is `=COUNTIF(A8:F20,0)`, and E3 is `=COUNT(A8:F20)-C3-D3`.

Comment: @YowE3K  i tried to do count IF's initally but I was trying to do the logic calculations per row so looking at each cell in the row of the selected range if all are zero then count as one the answer below is very close and its working perfectly almost just counting each cell and incrementing it that way instead of counting as one for the whole row but ill hopefully figure it out but if you ahve any suggestions id appreciate it you can see my attempt below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments there are numerous spelling mistakes that will prevent your code form working.  You can avoid this by using `Option Explicit`.

Here is a cleaned up version of your code.  I tried to keep it close to your original with the exception of adding in the `Select Case`

```
Option Explicit
Sub logicop()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rowi As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim andfunc, notfunc, result1, result2, result3

    Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myRange = wks.Range("A8:F20") 'go into each row of column

    andfunc = 1 'AND operaton
    notfunc = 0 'NOT function
    result1 = 0
    result2 = 0
    result3 = 0

    For Each rowi In myRange.Rows
        For Each cell In rowi.Cells  'go into each cell of the rows in rowi
            Select Case cell.Value
                Case notfunc
                    result1 = result1 + 1
                Case andfunc
                    result2 = result2 + 1
                Case Else
                    result3 = result3 + 1
            End Select
        Next cell
    Next rowi

    'Output results to specific cells
    wks.Cells(3, 3).Value = result1
    wks.Cells(3, 4).Value = result2
    wks.Cells(3, 5).Value = result3
End Sub
```

---

Note that an empty cell will be counted as 0 the way that it's written.  I'm assuming you have data in every cell within your range so that wont be a problem.

---

Example Result:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Per comments, I've updated the code to count which rows had all 0's, 1's or mixed.

```
Option Explicit
Sub logicop()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rowi As Range
    Dim andfunc, notfunc, result1, result2, result3, rowSum

    Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myRange = wks.Range("A8:F20") 'go into each row of column

    andfunc = 1 'AND operaton
    notfunc = 0 'NOT function
    result1 = 0
    result2 = 0
    result3 = 0

    For Each rowi In myRange.Rows
        rowSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rowi)

        Select Case rowSum / rowi.Cells.Count
            Case notfunc
                result1 = result1 + 1
            Case andfunc
                result2 = result2 + 1
            Case Else
                result3 = result3 + 1
        End Select
    Next rowi

    'Output results to specific cells
    wks.Cells(3, 3).Value = result1
    wks.Cells(3, 4).Value = result2
    wks.Cells(3, 5).Value = result3
End Sub
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help thats what i was trying to do and apologies for spelling mistakes I wasn't at my laptop where i did this. The way i set up my code is a bit off maybe, The case statments are ofcourse counting the values of the cell but i want to do the logic operations if all the values in all the cells in say row one are 0 count as one and keep incrementing eg. `Set myRange = Range("A1:B3")`
 And all the values in row one are 0'S count as one but what the code is doing now its counting as three so perhaps it could be the way i set up my code but any suggestions?

Comment: i was thinking of maybe just dividing result1 by the no. of columns in the range selected but Im not quite sure how to do that I tried doing  `wks.Cells(3, 3).Value = result1/cell `
but ofcourse im getting an error

Comment: @dfgool I edited my post to include another code set based on your comment.  I think this is what your looking for.  Give it a try and see if I understood you correctly.  Cheers